# Total ground time

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataset from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/usdot/flight-delays?select=flights.csv) that contains information about flights. A glimpse of the dataset is shown below

[image]

I want to create a new dataset that should contain the aggregate view on the airplane,
for each flight day, each airline, total availability and total night_availability, where total availability is the total time that each aircraft was not flying in each flight day (ground time) and night availability is the ground time available between 23:00 and 07:00.

For example a plane can flight many times during each day

[image]

, I can find the total flight time for a plane for a day by summarizing the times (in minutes)  of the column ELAPSED_TIME. Then the ground time is the difference of the total minutes of a day and the sum of the ELAPSED_TIME column.

How can I create this dataset using pandas?

Edit:

To create the dataset I followed these steps:

```
import pandas as pd

# read dataset
flights = pd.read_csv('flights.csv',
                      dtype = {'DEPARTURE_TIME': object, 'ARRIVAL_TIME': object},
                      low_memory=False)
# keep only columns of interest
F = flights[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 
                           'DAY_OF_WEEK', 'AIRLINE',
                           'FLIGHT_NUMBER', 'TAIL_NUMBER',
                           'DEPARTURE_TIME', 'ARRIVAL_TIME', 
                           'ELAPSED_TIME', 'CANCELLED']]
# drop rows contain na 
f = F.dropna()
# format columns to datetime
f['DEPARTURE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(f['DEPARTURE_TIME'],format='%H%M', errors='coerce').dt.time

f['ARRIVAL_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(f['ARRIVAL_TIME'], format='%H%M', errors = 'coerce').dt.time
```

Comment: If ellapsed_time is known you can just do the following DF["Total time"]=24*60-DF["ellapsed_time"]

Comment: @HakanAkgün the thing is that each plane can have many flights during each day and I have to sum all the elapse_time values for every day for the plane.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

# read dataset
flights = pd.read_csv('flights.csv',
                      dtype = {'DEPARTURE_TIME': object, 'ARRIVAL_TIME': object},
                      low_memory=False)
# keep only columns of interest
F = flights[['YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 
                           'DAY_OF_WEEK', 'AIRLINE',
                           'FLIGHT_NUMBER', 'TAIL_NUMBER',
                           'DEPARTURE_TIME', 'ARRIVAL_TIME', 
                           'ELAPSED_TIME', 'CANCELLED']]
# drop rows contain na 
f = F.dropna()

# according to your method of elapsed time sum 

df2=f.groupby(['TAIL_NUMBER','YEAR','MONTH','DAY'])['ELAPSED_TIME'].sum().reset_index()
df2['ground_time']=24*60-df2['ELAPSED_TIME']
print(df2)
```

Now for the second part where you needed night total ground time  assume a is departure time and b is arrival time .

## for the part which requires you to calculate the night  total ground time

```
#logic is here 
#if b>a 
    # if b<=7
    #    return b-a
    # if b>=7 and a<=7
    #    if b>=23
    #       return (b-23 )+(7-a)
    #     else 
    #    return 7-a
    # if b>=23 and a>=23
    #    return b-a
    # if b>=23 
    #   return b-23

# if b<a
    # if b<7 and a>23 we need to do b-a
    # if b>7 and a>23 we need to do 7-a
    # if b<7 and a<23 we need to do b-23
    # if b>7 and a<23 we need to do 7-23

def change(x):

    a=pd.to_datetime(x['DEPARTURE_TIME'],format='%H%M',errors='coerce')
    b=pd.to_datetime(x['ARRIVAL_TIME'],format='%H%M',errors='coerce')
    c=pd.to_datetime("2300",format='%H%M')
    d=pd.to_datetime("0700",format='%H%M')
    if b>a :
        if b<=d :
            return pd.Timedelta(b-a).seconds/60.0;
        if b>=d and a<=d:
            if b>=c:
                return (pd.Timedelta(b-c).seconds/60.0)+pd.Timedelta(d-a).seconds/60.0;
            else :
                return pd.Timedelta(d-a).seconds/60.0;
        if b>=c and a>=c:
            return pd.Timedelta(b-a).seconds/60.0;
        if b>=c :
            return pd.Timedelta(b-c).seconds/60.0;
        else :
            return 0
        
    else:       
        if b<=d and a>=c :
            return pd.Timedelta(b-a).seconds/60.0 ;
        if b>=d and a>=c :
            return pd.Timedelta(d-a).seconds/60.0 ;
        if b<=d and a<=c :
            return pd.Timedelta(b-c).seconds/60.0;
        if b>=d and a<=c :
            return pd.Timedelta(d-c).seconds/60.0;
        return 0

#night_flight_time is the time spent between departure and arrival which lies in between (23:00 and 07:00)
f['night_flight_time']=f.apply(change,axis=1)
#print(f)
df3=f.groupby(['TAIL_NUMBER','YEAR','MONTH','DAY'])['night_flight_time'].sum().reset_index()
# here i have subtracted the night_flight_time  from total night duration i.e. 8 hours 
df3['night_ground_time']=8*60-df3['night_flight_time']
print(df3)
```

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct about the total ground time. How to find also the night total ground time?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the solution to the part which required you to find night total ground time

Comment: Tried the solution but I get 480(=8h) night ground time for all the planes.

Comment: can you check whether the csv files has departure time and arrival time in proper format like it may happen csv has '2' for '0002' . I run the code directly in kaggle online server and i got results perfectly fine that is why i feel it may have been the case after downloading csv file the f['DEPARTURE_TIME']  is in wrong format

Comment: yes, it is in '0002'  format.

Comment: You can check my kaggle notebook i created here at this link https://www.kaggle.com/harshitsharma007/notebooke6526c56ea

Comment: yes, but the process it too slow.